# Using Raphaël with ZPD (Zoom-Panning-Drag) plugin - Zooming doesn't go with cursor

Tags: svg, raphael, zooming, drag

I use Raphäel and the Raphäel Sketchpad library to create a sketchpad in the browser, which works fine. I have implemented Rapäel ZPD (https://github.com/andrewseddon/raphael-zpd) to do panning/zooming on the sketchpad/SVG container div. When I zoom out and back in, the cursor gets misplaced (Firefox/Chrome).

I have identified the following code in ZPD that causes the position of the cursor to go wrong when zooming or dragging:

```
/**
 * Instance an SVGPoint object with given event coordinates.
 */
me.getEventPoint = function(evt) {
    var p = me.root.createSVGPoint();
    p.x = evt.clientX;
    p.y = evt.clientY;
    return p;
};
```

SVGPan, which ZPD in built from, has the same issue: http://code.google.com/p/svgpan/issues/detail?id=14&can=1&q=zoom. However, none of the suggestions in the reported issue seem to work. Any advice on how or why this offset happens and any solution to it?

Comment: I don't know about Raphael ZPD, but if you don't find a solution, you can create zooming and panning functionality in Raphael 2.1 using its viewbox functions. It's not very well documented and not the easiest thing to set up, but it's an option and works pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the developer of Raphaël ZPD has abandoned his code. I think the problem lies in scaling issues within Raphaël Sketchpad. However, reviewing and editing the code base for hours now, I haven't found a solution.